# Too many levels of symbolic links on current directory?

Tags: android, linux, git, unix, repository

I'm getting the following error when doing a simple "ls" in a directory on an NFS share on Ubuntu 11.10.

```
user@host[/android-master/external/iptables/extensions]
> ls -al
ls: reading directory .: Too many levels of symbolic links
total 580
drwxrwxr-x  2 stephen stephen 12288 2011-12-28 17:16 .
drwxrwxr-x 11 stephen stephen  4096 2011-12-28 17:16 ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 stephen stephen   229 2011-12-28 17:16 filter_init
-rw-rw-r--  1 stephen stephen  6594 2011-12-28 17:16 GNUmakefile.in
-rw-rw-r--  1 stephen stephen  3286 2011-12-28 17:16 libip6t_ah.c
-rw-rw-r--  1 stephen stephen  4595 2011-12-28 17:16 libip6t_dst.c
-rw-rw-r--  1 stephen stephen   363 2011-12-28 17:16 libip6t_eui64.c
```

I'm confused as to why I'm getting this.  The current directory isn't a symlink (confirmed by ls on parent).

Also, when I do the same "ls" on an Ubuntu 10.04 machine mounting the same NFS path, it doesn't have this problem.

This is from the external/iptables/extensions directory of the android open source project.  Maybe it's repo/git related?  I do see a lot of broken symlinks in the .git directories of all the projects:

```
user@host[/android-master/external/iptables/.git]
> ls -al
total 48
drwxrwxr-x  2 stephen stephen  4096 2011-12-28 17:16 .
drwxrwxr-x 11 stephen stephen  4096 2011-12-28 17:16 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 stephen stephen    52 2011-12-28 17:16 config -> ../../../.repo/projects/external/iptables.git/config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 stephen stephen    57 2011-12-28 17:16 description -> ../../../.repo/projects/external/iptables.git/description
-rw-rw-r--  1 stephen stephen    41 2011-12-28 17:16 HEAD
lrwxrwxrwx  1 stephen stephen    51 2011-12-28 17:16 hooks -> ../../../.repo/projects/external/iptables.git/hooks
-rw-rw-r--  1 stephen stephen 35645 2011-12-28 17:16 index
lrwxrwxrwx  1 stephen stephen    50 2011-12-28 17:16 info -> ../../../.repo/projects/external/iptables.git/info
lrwxrwxrwx  1 stephen stephen    50 2011-12-28 17:16 logs -> ../../../.repo/projects/external/iptables.git/logs
lrwxrwxrwx  1 stephen stephen    53 2011-12-28 17:16 objects -> ../../../.repo/projects/external/iptables.git/objects
lrwxrwxrwx  1 stephen stephen    57 2011-12-28 17:16 packed-refs -> ../../../.repo/projects/external/iptables.git/packed-refs
lrwxrwxrwx  1 stephen stephen    50 2011-12-28 17:16 refs -> ../../../.repo/projects/external/iptables.git/refs
lrwxrwxrwx  1 stephen stephen    54 2011-12-28 17:16 rr-cache -> ../../../.repo/projects/external/iptables.git/rr-cache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 stephen stephen    49 2011-12-28 17:16 svn -> ../../../.repo/projects/external/iptables.git/svn
```

packed-refs and svn are broken links.  Not sure why, that's something else I'll have to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the actual "ls" command, rather than your shell's built-in:

```
> /bin/ls -al
```